# Global Array in a C++ Object

Tags: c++, arrays

Ok so here is my issue, I have a global array declared in a class. I use a function in that class to assign values to the array, values which are passed as an argument to that function. (this works) I then have another function which is in the same class as the array and the first function, but is called from another class; but when it is called from the other class the global array is all zero'd out.

[This is a picture to the actual issue in the function that is not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pRgs7.png)

[Here is the function that saves the data to the array, as you can see it works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w8VNZ.png)

Here is the code as an example:

```
    //
    //  Player.cpp
    //  Battleship
    //
    //  Created by Cody Flies on 5/25/16.
    //  Copyright © 2016 Cody Flies. All rights reserved.
    //

    #include "Player.hpp"
    #include <string.h>
    #include "Utility.hpp"


    std::string Player::getName(){
        return name;
    }
    void Player::setName(std::string name){
        this->name = name;
    }
    int Player::getNumberShipsLeft(){
        return numbershipsleft;
    }
    void Player::setNumberOfShipsLeft(int numberOfShipsLost){
        this->numbershipsleft -= numberOfShipsLost;
    }
    /// set the location of the ships and store them in the players        variables
    void Player::setCarrierLocation(int x, int y, int direction){
        carrierLocation[0] = x;// <5 is x values
        carrierLocation[5] = y;// >= 5 is y values
        if(direction == 1){
            for(int i = 0; i<5; i++){
                carrierLocation[i] = i+x;
            }
            for(int i = 5; i<10; i++){
                carrierLocation[i] = y;
            }
        }
        if(direction == 0){
            for(int i = 5; i<10; i++){
                carrierLocation[i] = i+y-5;
            }
            for(int i = 0; i<5; i++){
                carrierLocation[i] = x;
            }
        }
    }

    void Player::printContents(){
        for (auto i : carrierLocation) std::cout<<i<<std::endl; }

    /*
    void setCruiserLocation(int pos[10][10]);
    void setDestroyerLocation(int pos[10][10]);
    void setPatrolBoatLocation(int pos[10][10]);*/
    /// get the location of the ships
    bool Player::isCarrierHit(int x, int y){
        for(int i = 0; i<10; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j<10; j++){
                if(x==carrierLocation[i]&&y==carrierLocation[j])
                    return true; /// this is where the carrierLocatio
                                 /// is not holding the info.
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    /*int* getCruiserLocation(){
    }
    int* getDestroyerLocation();
    int* getPatrolBoatLocation();*/
```

and here is the Player.hpp--->

```
    class Player
    {

    /// variables name, shipsleft
    private:
        std::string name;
        int numbershipsleft;
        //int cruiserLocation[1];
        int carrierLocation[10];
        /*int destroyerLocation[10][10];
        int patrolBoatLocation[10][10];
        */

    /// getters and setters for name and shipsleft
    ///
    public:

        std::string getName();
        void setName(std::string);
        int getNumberShipsLeft();
        void setNumberOfShipsLeft(int);
        /// set the location of the ships and store them in the players variables
        void setCarrierLocation(int, int, int);/*
        void setCruiserLocation(int pos[10][10]);
        void setDestroyerLocation(int pos[10][10]);
        void setPatrolBoatLocation(int pos[10][10]);*/
        /// get the location of the ships
        bool isCarrierHit(int, int);/*
        int* getCruiserLocation();
        int* getDestroyerLocation();
        int* getPatrolBoatLocation();*/
        void printContents();




    };

    #endif /* Player_hpp */
```

and here is where the object is called.

```
    //
    //  Board.cpp
    //  Battleship
    //
    //  Created by Cody Flies on 5/25/16.
    //  Copyright © 2016 Cody Flies. All rights reserved.
    //

    #include "Board.hpp"
    #include <string.h>
    #include <iostream>
    #include "Player.hpp"
    using namespace std;


    void Board::createBoard(){
        int shipPlacement, startCol, startRow, shipSize;
        char matrix[10][10];
        //call method to get user information and set ship locations
        userInput();


        startCol = 2;
        startRow = 3;
        shipSize = 5;
        string value;

        for(int row = 0; row<10; row++){
            for(int column = 0; column<10; column++){
                matrix[row][column] = 126;
                if(player1.isCarrierHit(row, column)){
                    matrix[row][column] = 'A';
                }
            }
        }
        string space = "  ";
        cout << "   1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10" << endl;
        for(int i = 0; i<10; i++){
            if(i == 9){
                space = " ";
            }
            cout << i+1 << space;
            for(int j = 0; j<10; j++){
                cout << matrix[i][j] << " ";
            }
            cout << endl;
        }

        player1.printContents();
    }

    void Board::userInput(){
        string playername;
        cout << "how many players? " << endl;
        int players;
        cin >> players;
        if(players == 1){
            player2.setName("Computer");
            cout << "what is your name" << endl;
            cin >> playername;
            player1.setName(playername);
            placeShips(player1);

        }
        else if(players == 2){
            cout << "what is your name player 1" << endl;
            cin >> playername;
            player1.setName(playername);
            cout << "what is your name player 2" << endl;
            cin >> playername;
            player2.setName(playername);
            placeShips(player1);
            placeShips(player2);
        }

        cout << "your name is: " << player1.getName() << " and your opponents name is: " << player2.getName() << endl;

    }

    void Board::placeShips(Player player){
        int coord[2];
        int direction;
        cout << "what coordinates would you like your Carrier to start"<<endl;
        cin >> coord[0] >> coord[1];
        cout << "what direction would you like your ship 0 for vertical 1 for horizontal" << endl;
        cin >> direction;
        player.setCarrierLocation(coord[0], coord[1], direction);


    }

    Board::Board(){
    }
```

and Board.hpp

```
    //
    //  Board.hpp
    //  Battleship
    //
    //  Created by Cody Flies on 5/25/16.
    //  Copyright © 2016 Cody Flies. All rights reserved.
    //

    #ifndef Board_hpp
    #define Board_hpp

    #include <stdio.h>
    #include "Utility.hpp"
    #include "Player.hpp"

    class Board
    {
    private:
         Player player2, player1;
    public:
    // a method to create the board
        void createBoard();
        bool isShip(char, char, char, char);
        void placeShips(Player);
        int attachShip(int, int, int, int);
        void userInput();
        Board();


    };

    #endif /* Board_hpp */
```

and the main file

```
    //
    //  main.cpp
    //  Battleship
    //
    //  Created by Cody Flies on 5/25/16.
    //  Copyright © 2016 Cody Flies. All rights reserved.
    //

    #include <iostream>
    #include "Board.hpp"
    #include "Player.hpp"
    using namespace std;

    int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
        //run BattleSpace Class
        Board board;
        board.createBoard();




        //carrier 5
        //battleship 4
        //crusier 3
        //sub 3
        //destroyer 2


        return 0;
    }
```

This code is the code that I have used in Xcode.

Comment: What is it `a = aClass;` ?

Comment: `a = aClass;` should be `a aClass;` Also `a::inArray` should return `false` if `number` is not found.

Comment: "a" is the object and the aClass is a variable that stores that object, differing variables mean different objects with the same class, thats how I understand it at least

Comment: fair enough I will fix it as in my original code (i.e. not the sample i typed up) it is how you say it is.

Comment: Are you sure the array `globalArray` contains all `0`s? Have you tried printing its contents (i.e. add a function to `a` to print `globalArray` contents: `a::printContents() { for (auto i : globalArray) std::cout<<i<<std::endl; }`)

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Yes, I tested that method you just gave me an it returns all zero's when there should not be.

Comment: @Tas I tried the method and it still returns all zero's.

Comment: @n.m fixed thanks.

Comment: @Michael fixed thanks.

Comment: @Ari0nhh fixed thanks

Comment: This is normally called *member variable*, not "global".  Each instance of the class has its own copy of the member variable.

Comment: `fixed` No it's not. there are still curly braces misplaced. Which, incidentally, might have something to do with your error.

Comment: @M.M ok I understand that, but shouldn't each instance be able to store the information based on that instance of the class

Comment: [cannot reproduce](http://ideone.com/2p9iCN)

Comment: Please do not post images (screenshots) of code! We cannot copy and paste into our editors. You should also better specify the expected behavior if my guess was not correct. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Melebius I uploaded the code..

Comment: @KarstenKoop I fixed the problem with stack overflow hopefully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aside from all the other issues with your code, the problem probably stems from your term "global array" which is misleading.

```
class A {
    int array[10];
};
```

`array` here is a *member variable*, every *instance* of class A has it's own discrete copy of `array`. It is not global, it is not shared. As a result, here is your problem:

```
void Board::placeShips(Player player){
```

`placeShips` takes a Player by *value* meaning it makes a copy. The changes made to `player` will affect this copy of player until the end of the function at which point the instance called `player` is destroyed, leaving the `player` you passed in to it unaffected.

What you need here is to pass by reference, because you want to change the instance you are being called with:

```
void Board::placeShips(Player& player){
```

Practical demonstration:

```
#include <iostream>

int fValue(int i) {  // is ia local variable
    i = 10;
}  // i destroyed

int fRef(int& i) {
    i = 42;
}

int main() {
    int i = 1;
    std::cout << "main:i=" << i << "\n";
    fValue(i);
    std::cout << "after fValue i=" << i << "\n";  // unchanged
    fRef(i);
    std::cout << "after fRef i=" << i << "\n";  // prints 42
}
```

See http://ideone.com/LMh0xw

Comment: Thank you, I started learning object oriented programming with Java so pointers and &'s are still new to me but we learn something new everyday right.

Answer (score 3):

The question contains several possible issues: a few questionable statements and a lot of misleading names and comments.

- A **class** is a template for creating objects, an **object** is an instance of a class. So the variable name `aClass` is misleading.
- A **global variable** is defined outside class. A **member variable** is a variable defined inside a class and there is a specific instance for each object of the class. The variable `a::globalArray` is a standard member variable here. (There are also **static member variables** which can be considered *class-global*. However, non-static member variables like `a::globalArray` are simply *object-local* and a comment cannot change this.)
- The member function (**method**) `a::assignToArray(int number)` (as it’s currently written) takes a number and fills the whole array with the numbers starting with `number` and ending with `number + 9`. It might be the desired behavior but I would definitely name the method differently, for example `fillArray()`.

Let’s focus on the non-working method `a::isInArray()` now. The current implementation should be called something like `arrayBeginsWith()`. Why? **It returns after the first round of the for-loop!** It just looks at the first item in the array, compares it to the parameter and returns `true` if they equal and `false` otherwise.

So what should a real `isInArray()` look like? Well, it’s not so far different:

```
bool a::isInArray(int number){
    for(int i = 0; i<10; i++){ // go through the whole array
        if(globalArray[i] == number){// test for equality
            return true;             // return ONLY IF equals
        }
    }
    return false; // for-loop has finished now without returning true
}
```

I have just moved the statement `return false;` **after** the for-loop, so it’s not called in the first round. I’ve also rewritten the comments to match the code better.

And don’t forget to write the closing braces `}` to close both methods!

OK, let’s test it now: http://ideone.com/rzes2b

Comment: Please see attached pictures that I just uploaded, you are correct but that is not my issue I apologize for the typos.

Comment: @cflies1121 Well, you haven’t told us yet what your issue _is_.

Comment: I tried to delete question but it won't let me so I am going to reword everything.